# Go mongodb driver ignores pipeline in aggregation

Tags: mongodb, go

Based on the example found on https://github.com/simagix/mongo-go-examples/blob/master/examples/aggregate_array_test.go I created the code below that runs a pipeline on a collection:

```
pipeline := `[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year: "$action_date" },
                month: { $month: "$action_date" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$action_date" },
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]`

var doc bson.M
var cur *mongo.Cursor
collection := apiContext.MongoClient.Database(apiContext.DatabaseName).Collection(util.ActionCollection)

opts := options.Aggregate()
if cur, err = collection.Aggregate(ctx, MongoPipeline(pipeline), opts); err != nil {
}
defer cur.Close(ctx)
for cur.Next(ctx) {
    cur.Decode(&doc)
    fmt.Println(doc["count"])
}
```

I don't get any errors but the output is not what I expect it to be. Instead of returning count of documents based on dates, I get all of the documents in the collection.

I don't know what I am missing but shouldn't I get the grouped results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know what I am missing but shouldn't I get the grouped results?

There are few things to point out here. The code example uses `github.com/simagix/keyhole/mdb` module for [MongoPipeline](https://github.com/simagix/keyhole/blob/v1.3.0/mdb/pipeline.go#L14). This function is supposed to take your string formatted MongoDB pipeline `$group` and converts into [bson](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson). This is a format that [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) uses to send to MongoDB server.

Unfortunately the `MongoPipeline` function does not return any `error` that your code could catch, but the function is using `encoding/json` module to convert the pipeline into `bson`, and there are errors. The JSON parse errors that you're getting are:

- `invalid character '$' looking for beginning of object key string` => Because keys need to be wrapped with `"`
- `invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string` => Because there are extra comma(s) after `}`.

Due to these errors the `MongoPipeline` returns empty array `[]`, which means undefined Aggregation Pipeline, and will return all documents in the collection.

The correct pipeline JSON string is (you can use [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com) to validate)

```
[{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": {
                "$year": "$action_date"
            },
            "month": {
                "$month": "$action_date"
            },
            "day": {
                "$dayOfMonth": "$action_date"
            }
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}]
```

Depending on your use case, you can skip the `keyhole/mdb` and `encoding/json` modules, and use `bson` directly. For example:

```
groupStage := `{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$action_date" },
            "month": { "$month": "$action_date" },
            "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$action_date" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}`


var group bson.M 
err = bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(groupStage), false, &group)
if err!=nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

var doc bson.M 

// You can add another stage i.e. bson.A{group, sort, project}
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(context.Background(), bson.A{group})
defer cursor.Close(context.Background())
if err!=nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [mongo.Pipeline](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Pipeline) with [bson.M](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) or [bson.D](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#D) directly:

```
pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
        {{"$group", bson.D{
                {"_id",   bson.D{
                        {"year", bson.D{{"$year", "$action_date"}}},
                        {"month", bson.D{{"$month", "$action_date"}}},
                        {"day", bson.D{{"$dayOfMonth", "$action_date"}}}
                }},
                {"count", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}},
        }}},
}
```

The example above is written with current stable [MongoDB Go driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) v1.1.3.